# Is a Windows service a good place to store and expose encrypted keys for a web server app?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api, encryption, windows-services

Windows service a good place to store and expose encrypted keys for a web server app?

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems to be based on the premise that there is a common need to store and expose encrypted keys... for some purpose. Without knowing how this requirement arose, it's difficult to know how best it is dealt with.

Comment: The requirement is the safe storage and transfer of data. The data is a key for encryption and decryption within a web app. The key itself will be generated in the windows service and kept encrypted in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't.
For encryption related keys you should look to a service like [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) to store them.
For more regular stuff like IDs and secrets used to access online services (like APIs) you can simply store the secrets as a [slot setting](http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/using-deployment-slot-settings-in-azure-web-apps/) on your web app (that way your secret doesn't have to be persisted in source control with the rest of the app's code and configuration).

Comment: Will slot settings work for mobile apps too? Asking since the mobile app is not on a server. The mobile app is Xamarin C# based.

Comment: @StackMan no, slot settings only work for web delivered content - although they do work for web/WCF services. So if you make a call to the web service to do the work that requires access to the secret then you'll be good.

Comment: That last sentence seems fuzzy to me. Can you elaborate please? Thanks.

Comment: I should note that this suggestion is based on Azure functionality. Just have your mobile app talk to a web service, that web service can then do the work that requires the secret, that secret can be sourced from the slot level app settings on the web service.